# What is the best way in Perl to iterate a loop and extract pairs or triples

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a flat array of coordinates and I want to iterate and extract pairs of x and y coordinates. The same logic could apply to triples for RGB colors. This is what I have so far, but it doesn't feel super flexible or elegant.

```
my @coords = qw(1 5 2 6 3 8 6 12 7 5);

for (my $i = 0; $i < @coords; $i += 2) {
    my $x = $coords[$i];
    my $y = $coords[$i+1];

    print "$x, $y\n";
}
```

There has to be a better way to do this right?

Answer (score 7):

The module [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils) has `natatime` (n-at-a-time)

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(natatime);

my @ary = 1..12; 

my $it = natatime 3, @ary;  # iterator

while (my @triplet = $it->()) { say "@triplet" }
```

Answer (score 5):

`splice` is a better way

```
while (my ($x,$y) = splice @coords, 0, 2) {
    ...
}
```

Two things to note.

1. `splice` consumes the elements of `@coords`. If you don't want your loop to destroy the contents of your array, use a temporary array.

   ```
      my @tmp = @coords;
      while (my ($x,$y) = splice @tmp,0,2) { ... }
   ```
2. If the input might not contain an even number of elements, you may want to add an additional check to make sure each iteration has access to the right number of elements

   ```
      while (2 == (my ($x,$y) = splice @coords,0,2)) { ... }
   ```

Comment: I think you meant `splice @tmp, ...` in your second example.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`pairs`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util#pairs) from the core [`List::Util`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util) module to turn an even-number of elements list into a list of two-element array refs:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use List::Util qw/pairs/;

my @coords = qw(1 5 2 6 3 8 6 12 7 5);

for my $pair (pairs @coords) {
    my ($x, $y) = @$pair;
    # ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

An old school aproach to the problem

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @coords = qw(1 5 2 6 3 8 6 12 7 5);
my($x,$y);

while( ($x,$y,@coords) = @coords ) {
    say "$x, $y";
}
```

Output

```
1, 5
2, 6
3, 8
6, 12
7, 5
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `shift` in a `while` loop.

```pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @coords = qw/1 5 2 6 3 8 6 12 7 5/;
my ($x, $y);

while (@coords) {
    $x = shift @coords;
    $y = shift @coords;
    # another shift to get triples

    # Do something with $x, $y, ...
    say "$x, $y";
}
```

The while loop runs until `@coords` is empty. `shift` gets the first element out and deletes it from the array.

### Avoid `undef` by giving a default value:

If you try above with triples, you'll get an error because there will be undefined values in the last run. `$x` will be `5` and then `@coords` is empty.

So give a default value using `//`.

```pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @coords = qw/1 5 2 6 3 8 6 12 7 5/;
my ($x, $y, $z);

while (@coords) {
    $x = shift @coords; # is defined!
    $y = shift @coords // "<undef>";
    $z = shift @coords // "<undef>";

    # ...
}
```

Don't use `||`! Because `shift @coords || "<undef>";` will be `"<undef>"` if the current value is evaluated to false (`0`, `""`, ...).

Answer (score 2):

I like to use splice without overworking it by passing the result through as the test, and also add a guard condition:

```
@triples % 3 and die "TRIPLES ARRAY NOT MULTIPLE OF 3 IN LENGTH";
while (@triples){
    my ($foo, $bar, $baz) = splice @triples, 0, 3;
    ...
}
```

in case you need @triples to survive getting consumed by the ellided code within the loop, make copies, either of the whole array or with offsets while incrementing an index. TMTOWTDI.